# How to send Date formatted with Z and T to an API using Retrofit?

Tags: android, rest, date, kotlin, retrofit

I have the following example path to my API -

`base_url/path/{country}/path/path?from=2020-03-01T00:00:00Z&to=2020-03-02T00:00:00Z`

So I need to pass 2 Date objects using the Z and T formatting and I can't really get how to format a new Kotlin Date() object into these Z and T formatting.

My current get method -

```kotlin
@GET("path/{country}/path/path/")
    suspend fun getCountryModelByDate(
        @Path("country") country: String,
        @Query("from") from : String,
        @Query("to") to : String
    ): Model
```

But when I try to test my method like the following -

```kotlin
class RemoteDataSource(private val api: Api) {

    suspend fun getCountryModelByDate(): Resource<Model> {
        return try {
            Resource.Success(coronaVirusApi.getCovidDeathsByDeathFromCountry("italy", Date().toString(), Date().toString()))
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            Resource.Exception(exception)
        }
    }

}
```

Which causes me to get the following 404 error, look at the URL that is being sent -

`Response{protocol=h2, code=404, message=, url=https://api.covid19api.com/country/italy/status/deaths/?from=Tue%20Nov%2017%2010%3A47%3A30%20GMT%2B02%3A00%202020&to=Tue%20Nov%2017%2010%3A47%3A30%20GMT%2B02%3A00%202020}`

So my questions are -

1. How do I format a Kotlin Date object to have a Z and T format like what I need for my API?
2. How can I send the formatted date into my query without it being gibrished out?

Comment: If you can use `Instant` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, you can just use `Instant.toString()` for generating ISO 8601 format — which is the name of your format with `T` and `Z`.

Comment: oh my gosh...I have spent WAY too much time on this. Thank you very much, please comment and I will approve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Instant.toString() from java.time

Your format with `T` and `Z` is ISO 8601. You may want to consult the link at the bottom. The classes of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, produce ISO 8601 from their `toString` methods. Use the `Instant` class. For a brief demonstration in Java:

```
    Instant i = Instant.now();
    System.out.println(i);
```

Example output:

> 2020-11-18T09:31:33.613965Z

If the `Instant` falls on midnight in UTC, as yours do, the output will be like:

> 2020-11-18T00:00:00Z

The presence of decimals on the seconds in the first case probably is no issue for your API since the fraction is optional according to the ISO 8601 standard. Should you want to get rid of it, it’s easiest to truncate the `Instant`:

```
    Instant instantToPrint = i.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(instantToPrint);
```

> 2020-11-18T09:31:33Z

> How can I make the instant object always return T00:00:00Z as this is
> what my API requires?

Edit: Given that you have already got an instant that falls on the desired day in UTC, just truncate to whole days:

```
    Instant instantToPrint = i.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

> 2020-11-18T00:00:00Z

The question is, though, where your date comes from. Using java.time a day in the calendar would be represented by a `LocalDate`, so we’d need to convert.

```
    LocalDate fromDate = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.MARCH, 1);
    Instant fromDateTimeUtc = fromDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
    System.out.println(fromDateTimeUtc);
```

> 2020-03-01T00:00:00Z

> 2. How can I send the formatted date into my query without it being gibrished out?

I believe that a colon in a URL needs to be URL encoded (except the colon after the protocol, the one in `https://`). So it should become `%3A`. The rest of the string from `Instant` should be clear to read.

### Links

- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.